# Angular Carousel using ngx-bootstrap

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, ngx-bootstrap

I have followed the [Getting started guide using angular-cli](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/docs/getting-started/ng-cli.md) and I had a complete demo using the Alert module. I have then tried to add a Carousel as described [here](http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/carousel#usage).

I don't have errors in the console, but the display looks wired and the Carousel is not functioning. This is how it looks 
[image]

The arrows work but the caption goes outside the image, a block of white to the right of the image.

I have copy-pasted the component code as well as the HTML, and I tried the first two examples on the above link to make sure.

Can someone please help me figure out this problem?

Answer (score 3):

In bootstrap 4.3.1, the `img-responsive` class was replaced by `img-fluid` and the `center-block` by `mx-auto`, but this last one should be used inside the `<slide>` tag, because the width property is not set on the `<img>` anymore.

So, with ngx-bootstrap 5.1.2 which uses bootstrap 4.3.1, the code should be like this (tested with Angular 7):

```
<carousel [itemsPerSlide]="itemsPerSlide"
          [singleSlideOffset]="singleSlideOffset"
          [noWrap]="noWrap"
          [interval]="cycleInterval"
          [startFromIndex]="0">
  <slide *ngFor="let slide of slides; let index=index" class="mx-auto">
    <img [src]="slide.image" class="img-fluid">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h4>Slide {{index}}</h4>
    </div>
  </slide>
</carousel>
```

The above code expects your component.ts file to contain the below code:

```
public itemsPerSlide = 3;
public singleSlideOffset = false;
public noWrap = false;
public cycleInterval = 3000;
public slides = [
  {image: '//placehold.it/1200x600/444'},
  {image: '//placehold.it/1200x600/ccff00'},
  {image: '//placehold.it/1200x600/ddd'},
  {image: '//placehold.it/1200x600/ccff00'},
  {image: '//placehold.it/1200x600/444'},
  {image: '//placehold.it/1200x600/ddd'}
];
```

Comment: This is correct as per latest versions, thanks @João Canhoto

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your images (`img` tag):

```
 class="img-responsive center-block"
```

...yet it helps to have all images same sized before loading them to make it look decent.

Bootstrap carousel does not auto resize images & center zoom in given area. If you want that effect you better use another carousel component (not `ngx-bootstrap` one)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fix this issue, (base on @Bogac's answer)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-2 push-md-2">
    <carousel>
      <slide *ngFor="let slide of slides; let index=index">
        <img [src]="slide.image" class="img-responsive center-block">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h4>Slide {{index}}</h4>
          <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
        </div>
      </slide>
    </carousel>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you have to had the dependencies installed.

```
npm install ngx-bootstrap bootstrap@4.0.0-beta jquery popper.js --save
```

**Example**

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <carousel>
                <slide>
                    <img src="../../../assets/img/img1.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h4>Test</h4>
                        <p>test</p>
                    </div>
                </slide>
                <slide>
                    <img src="../../../assets/img/img2.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h4>Test2</h4>
                        <p>test2</p>
                    </div>
                </slide>
            </carousel>
        </div>
    </div>
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { AlertModule } from '../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap';
import { CarouselModule } from '../../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/carousel';

imports: [...,
AlertModule.forRoot(),
CarouselModule.forRoot(),
.],
```

.angular-cli.json:

```
"styles": [
     "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "styles.css",
  ],
```