# Can't render images in multi slide carousel of ngx-bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ngx-bootstrap

so I am using ngx-bootstrap. When I am using single image carousel it works perfectly but in multi image all I am getting is the first image at the left and nothing else.

```
<p>
  If `true` - carousel indicators indicate slides chunks works ONLY if singleSlideOffset = FALSE
</p>
<carousel [itemsPerSlide]="itemsPerSlide"
          [singleSlideOffset]="false"
          [interval]="false"
          [indicatorsByChunk]="true">
  <slide *ngFor="let slide of slides; let index=index">
    <img [src]="slide.image" alt="image slide" style="display: block; width: 100%;">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h4>Slide {{index}}</h4>
    </div>
  </slide>
</carousel>
```

Below is the angular code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {  itemsPerSlide = 3;
  singleSlideOffset = false;
  noWrap = false;


  slides = [
    {image: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81GfZasnt9L._SL1371_.jpg'},
    {image: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81GfZasnt9L._SL1371_.jpg'},
    {image: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81GfZasnt9L._SL1371_.jpg'},
    {image: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81GfZasnt9L._SL1371_.jpg'},
    {image: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81GfZasnt9L._SL1371_.jpg'},
    {image: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81GfZasnt9L._SL1371_.jpg'},
    {image: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81GfZasnt9L._SL1371_.jpg'},
    {image: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81GfZasnt9L._SL1371_.jpg'},
    {image: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81GfZasnt9L._SL1371_.jpg'},
    {image: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81GfZasnt9L._SL1371_.jpg'}
  ];

}
```

Btw this code is right from the ngx bootstrap documentation and the image I picked from google. I know its not a good sign if the documentation code isn't working but maybe I am missing something and I'd be glad if someone who may have encountered similar problem can help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hello just add this class `mx-auto` in the slides, working for me :) :

```
  <slide *ngFor="let slide of slides; let index=index" class="mx-auto">
     ...
  </slide>
```

If you prefer you can add the following css to your slides :

```
margin-left: auto !important;
margin-right: auto !important;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, can't believe it was a margin issue. I was surprised the documentation code as is wasn't working.

Comment: Yeah I had the same problem before,  because In bootstrap 4.3.1, the img-responsive class was replaced by img-fluid and the center-block by mx-auto, but this last one should be used inside the <slide> tag, because the width property is not set on the <img> anymore. source : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43759957/angular-carousel-using-ngx-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Remove the added attributes like so

```
<carousel>
  <slide *ngFor="let slide of slides; let index=index">
    <img [src]="slide.image" alt="image slide" style="display: block; width: 100%;">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h4>Slide {{index}}</h4>
    </div>
  </slide>
</carousel>
```